# Hive Execution Error

Tags: hadoop, avro, apache-hive

I am new to avro and hive and while learning it i got some confusion. Using

`tblproperties('avro.schema.url'='somewhereinHDFS/categories.avsc')`.

If I run this `create` command like

```
create table categories (id Int , dep_Id Int , name String) 
stored as avrofile  
tblproperties('avro.schema.url'=
'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/cloudera/data/retail_avro_avsc/categories.avsc')
```

but why should i use `id Int, dep_Id Int` in above command even if i am giving `avsc` file which contains complete schema.

```
create table categories stored as avrofile
tblproperties('avro/schema.url'=
'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/cloudera/data/retail_avro_avsc/categories.avsc')
```

> 

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException 
Encountered AvroSerdeException determining schema. 
Returning signal schema to indicate problem: 
Neither avro.schema.literal nor avro.schema.url specified, 
can't determine table schema)
```

Why does hive need to specify the schema even if the `avsc` file is present and it already contains the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to do it in this way?

```
CREATE TABLE categories
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='http://schema.avsc');
```

More info here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe

Answer (score 0):

Creating an external hive table `orders_sqoop` from given avro-schema file and avro-data file:

```
 hive> create external table if not exists orders_sqoop
        stored as avro
        location '/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders'
        tblproperties('avro.schema.url'='/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders_schema/orders.avsc');
```

The above `create table` command executes successfully and creates `orders_sqoop` table.

Validate the table structure below:

```
hive> show create table orders_sqoop;
OK
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `orders_sqoop`(
  `order_id` int COMMENT '', 
  `order_date` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `order_customer_id` int COMMENT '', 
  `order_status` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'avro.schema.url'='/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders_schema/orders.avsc', 
  'numFiles'='2', 
  'numRows'='-1', 
  'rawDataSize'='-1', 
  'totalSize'='660906', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1563093902')
Time taken: 0.125 seconds, Fetched: 21 row(s)
```

The above table created as expected.